# Ignore @Formula in one case

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have simple entity with field countUsing which specify count used in other table. It is subquery with annotation `Formula`.

And i would like in one case ignore execute query in formula but others subquery must invoke.

My entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "roles_id_seq", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "roles_id_seq", sequenceName = "roles_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "\"NAME\"")
    private String name;

    @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter.class)
    private LocalDateTime insertDate;

    @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter.class)
    private LocalDateTime updateDate;

    @Formula("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_roles us WHERE us.id_role = id)")
    private Integer countUsing;
}
```

How can i achive the target, i think about flag in any annotation for field `countUsing`.

Annotation `Formula` has got only `value` property.

Comment: So when would the formula need to be ignored? Could you just add that conditional _into_ the formula as an SQL `CASE...WHEN`?

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you want use FetchType.LAZY on this attribute.

Therefore, you can`t use LAZY directly in a @Formula attribute in your class.

The solution for this is create an wrapper Class, with a oneToOne relationship to your class that`s contain your formula attribute, like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role{
    ... /*other attributes*/

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "role")
    private RoleCounting roleCouting;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class RoleCounting{
    @Id
    @Column(name="id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Role role;

    @Formula("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_roles us WHERE us.id_role = id)")
    private Integer countUsing;
}
```

That way, the subquery will only be executed when you invoke:
`role.getRoleCounting().getCountUsing();`

Comment: this solution is for me low profesional but i will consider this approach

Comment: Unless you override @Formula implementation to allow lazy, this is the only solution. So please mark as correct if it works.